# How to deliver Soap request via .Net Console App

Tags: .net, wcf, soap, microservices, console-application

Today's challenge is delivering soap requests. What, how, where? Let me explain.

We want to create a console app project with .Net Technologies (it doesn't have to be the newest, core 3.1 is also acceptable).

This console app will get SOAP messages/requests.

Then it should deliver them to another point/local or online service.

Console app will be running 24/7. When it gets a request it will deliver to its target.
(you may think that is like a microservice, yeah sort of)

Have you seen or experienced sth like that?

Any advice, tip, guide, or reference project will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the wcf service will meet your requirements. It can generate, deliver, and return soap messages. You can try reading [this docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/getting-started-tutorial) to get it started.

Comment: thanks, I will try . If I can success, I let you know.